# Create a view using one table or another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to create a view that chooses between tables to select records. Here is the query I am trying to write.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vwTable2
AS
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2')
            THEN(SELECT fldKey, fldValue, fldDivRef
                    FROM tbl2
                    WHERE fldKey IN ('key1','key2','key3'))
            ELSE(SELECT fldKey, fldValue, 
                        CASE ISNUMERIC((PARSENAME(REPLACE(fldkey,':','.'),1)))
                            WHEN 1 THEN (PARSENAME(REPLACE(fldkey,':','.'),1))
                            ELSE -1
                        END AS fldDivRef
                FROM tbl1
                WHERE fldKey LIKE 'key1%' OR 
                        fldKey LIKE 'key2%' OR
                        fldKey LIKE 'key3%' OR)
        )
FROM sys.sysobjects
```

*I figured, sys.sysobjects is not going to work. I have just put it for reference, to show what I was trying to do.*

I got the select and case statement working in separate query. It's just I can not get it to work with view. Can anyone suggest, what I am doing wrong here or is there any other approach that I can try?

Comment: what do you mean cannot get it to work with view? Does it throw an error or sth else?

Comment: just not sure what should I put into the from section of the select statement. Or even this is the right approach for the  solution or not.

Comment: YOu tag SQL Server 2008 (which has been completely unsupported for almost a year), howeber, use `CREATE OR ALTER` which wasn't introduced until much more recent versions of SQL server. What version are you *actually* using?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind whether table 1 or tble 2 will be used - is it as simple as whether the table exists?

Comment: yes. it is. I just have to check is if the tbl2 exists or not. if exists then take data from tbl2 or use tbl1. We are in process of transitioning the data from 1 table to another. @DaleK

Comment: As for what you're trying to do, If the `EXISTS` clause isn't true, the `VIEW` will fail. You cannot reference objects that don't exist in a query. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: If thats truly your logic you can't create a view, your only option is a stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: WEll, you've now tagged 2014, but still, `CREATE OR ALTER` wasn't introduced until [2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3190548/update-introduces-create-or-alter-transact-sql-statement-in-sql-server)... You should really find out what version of SQL Server you're using. I suggest running `PRINT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: @DaleK Perfect. I will do it using stored procedure. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for improvising my question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vwTable2
AS
SELECT fldKey, fldValue, fldDivRef
FROM tbl2
WHERE fldKey IN ('key1','key2','key3')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2')

UNION ALL

SELECT fldKey, fldValue, 
    CASE ISNUMERIC((PARSENAME(REPLACE(fldkey,':','.'),1)))
        WHEN 1 THEN (PARSENAME(REPLACE(fldkey,':','.'),1))
        ELSE -1
    END AS fldDivRef
FROM tbl1
WHERE (fldKey LIKE 'key1%' OR 
    fldKey LIKE 'key2%' OR
    fldKey LIKE 'key3%')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2')
```